# How do I suppress jQuery warnings for invalid email address?

Tags: jquery, validation, email, input, warnings

I'm using jQuery 2.2.0, and for CSS targeting I'm updating the value attribute to equal the value of the input on input events. Using a type of "email" results in a jQuery warning in the console every time the event fires, unless it's a valid email. This warning only shows up when updating the value attribute directly.

> The specified value "foo" is not a valid email address. -> jquery.min.js:3

Is there a way to temporarily suppress or disable this warning? Open the console and input something into the rendered snippet below to see.

```js
$('input').on('input', function () {
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="email">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a jQuery warning is HTML5.

When you put an invalid email value like `<input type="email" value="a">` it's gonna throw a warning because is not a valid email address.

So said this your function is forcing to put the introduced value to the value attribute, this refresh the DOM and make the validation every time the user introduce some text.

Try this in a fiddle

`<input type="email" value="a">`

and you'll see the warning.

You don't need to put the introduced value in the value attribute, you can just get it using `$('input').val()` or instead use the `<input type="text">` and do the validation with jQuery and some RegEx.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct. The console warning was just misleading to me.